# Integer equations

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, diophantine-equations

I have $2$ following problems. Find integer roots of

$$\begin{align}
&1)~\frac{x+y}{x^2-xy+y^2}=\frac3z \\
&2)~x^3y^3-4xy^3+y^2+x^2-2y-3=0
\end{align}$$

I have no idea to solve them. I try to guess roots of the second, they are $\left( -2, 1\right), \left( 0, -1\right), \left( 0, 3\right), \left( 2, 1\right) $. Please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: These problems seem very interesting. Where did you get them from?

Comment: @TobyMak These are my homework.

Comment: What class are you taking?

Comment: @TobyMak I'm in grade 9.

Comment: What lesson is this that you were given that exercise ?

Comment: To all other answerers: This user has posted some pretty advanced questions, so you don't have to use 9th grade math to solve this.

Comment: @Rebellos We are studying integer equations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Question 1:**

\begin{align}
& \frac{x+y}{x^2-xy+y^2} = \frac 3z \\
\iff & \frac{3(x^2-xy+y^2)}{x+y} = z\\
\iff & 3(x+y) - \frac{9xy}{x+y} = z \\
\iff & \frac{9xy}{x+y} = 3x+3y-z \\
\implies & \frac{9}{\frac 1x + \frac 1y} = 3x+3y-z
\end{align}

From the LHS we see that $\frac 1x + \frac 1y$ must be equal to $\pm 1, \pm 3, \pm 9$ since the RHS is an integer. But of course, since $x,y$ are integers, $\frac 1x + \frac 1y \in [-2,2]$ and it follows that $\frac 1x + \frac 1y = \pm 1$.

Moreover, the only way this can happen is if $x = y = \pm 2$.

Hence, the only solutions are $(x,y,z) = (2,2,3)$ and $(x,y,z) = (-2,-2,-3)$.

**EDIT:**

As pointed out in the comments, I have made the mistake of dividing by $0$, so I have changed the last $\iff$ to an $\implies$.

If $x=0$, then $z=3y$ so we get the solutions $(x,y,z) = (0,t,3t)$

Similarly when $y=0$ we get the solutions $(x,y,z) = (t,0,3t)$ for any $t \in \Bbb Z$ with $t \neq 0$.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's a nice answer, however, you forgot the cases when x and y are 0.

Comment: Yes, in this case, we get more solutions